# Windows Service running on a different port

Tags: windows-services

I have created a installer project (.net winforms) which when installed starts running as backend service (Windows service). I have configured the backend service to run on port 1000. The backend service will interact to mysql service to fetch data from database. Now when I install the msi the service is running on a different port other than 1000 like 50021. When I stop and run it again it runs on another port 50022. I have checked if the port 1000 is occupied using netstat cmd commands. This problem started occuring after a windows reset. Before that it was running on correct port(1000). I dont know how to proceed or debug the issue further. Got stuck for past 3days. Help me if possible.

Requirements:
NET Framework 4.0
• IIS 5.0
• MySQL 5.0 or MySQL 8.0

Im using mysql 8.0.32 and mysql odbc connector 3.51.

Answer (score 0):

Ports 0 to 1023 are reserved as per RFC 1700. Pick a different port number to use as your default.

Also make sure you're not looking at the client port (every socket uses two ports: the server port and the client port, which is completely different) or the post-connect port (after accepting a connection, a listener will commonly pass off the connection to an ephemeral port so it can immediately resume listening on the main port).

Other than that, we can't help you if you don't show the code for the service that opens the  socket for listening.

Comment: To remind you again with this , the problem is not with the code it is with the machine. Before windows reset it was working fine and it runs on correct port in other machines also. How to debug the problem with the machine.

Comment: @GokulCjGrove There are three ways we can go with this. `1)` We can accept the claim the problem is with the machine at face value, in which case our response MUST be to close the question, because it's defined as off-topic here (you should ask on ServerFault or SuperUser). `2)` We can take the claim at face value, but talk about how to respond with things controllable from a programming perspective, like using correct ports and evaluating the listening/connection code for workarounds. `3)` Challenge the premise, and look for places the observation might be tainted (ie client/ephemeral port).